# Typescript enumeration equality compile time error

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I am writing a basic implementation of user roles, to allow only certain users to access certain parts of the site, using typescript enumeration.

I have a string representing the user's primary role, e.g. "Manager", and I want to compare that with an enumerated type so I can implement ideas like 'users who are department manager *or higher* can see this information'.

This simple comparison does not seem to be working as documented (LHS should be returning a number), unless I'm missing something:

```
enum systemRoles {
  Staff,
  DeptMgr,
  Manager,
  GM,
  Executive,
  Owner
}

userTypeIsAuthorized(){
return systemRoles[this.currentUser().type] === 4
}
```

Writing userTypeIsAuthorized() as above gives a compiler error: "Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'". There is no error if I instead `return systemRoles['Executive'] === 4`, essentially hard-coding the user type rather than accessing the saved String type.

All of the above is really just me trying out the behavior of the enum type. What I ultimately want is something like (pseudocode):

`return systemRoles[this.currentUser().type] >= systemRoles['Executive'];
// return true if the user is an Executive or Owner.`

...but this produces a similar error: "Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'systemRoles'"

Maybe your solutions to my early misconceptions about the enum type will be useful to someone in the future if they are documented here!

EDIT: after reading through answers with clarification, I've arrived at this:

`return this.currentUser().type === systemRoles[systemRoles.Executive];`

This works as, essentially, a *string equality* comparison, but what I need is a numeric comparison within the enum type. In other words, the above works because "Executive" === "Executive", but what I need to return is (pseudocode): "Executive", the user's type, is greater than or equal to the system role Executive. So, if this.currentUser().type is "Owner", I need to return true -- not because the string "Owner" is greater than the string "Executive" (since O comes after E alphabetically) -- but because `Owner` has a higher numeric value (5) in the `enum` than `Executive` does (4). Put another way: if the enum had days of the week in it, I would like to return true if "Wednesday" is after Monday.

Comment: i have edited my answer you accomodate your edit

Answer (score 0):

You want to use enums, so use them right and to full advantage:

```
enum systemRoles {
  Staff,
  DeptMgr,
  Manager,
  GM,
  Executive,
  Owner
}

function userTypeIsAuthorized() {
    return this.currentUser().type === systemRoles.Executive;
}
```

Using enums means that you don't have to rely on an array index, but you can and always should the given alias. `this.currentUser().type` should already hold the enum value, so you just have to compare it to the wanted role.

Also outside a class a function name has to be prepended by the `function` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you index into an `enum` using a number index, you will get the name of that `enum` fields

```
declare var type: number;
var xx= systemRoles[type]; // xx will be of type string
```

So the compiler is right that you can't compare them.

You should just compare the value you have with an enum value

```
this.currentUser().type === systemRoles.Executive;
```

Comment: `this.currentUser().type === systemRoles.Executive;` compiles, but when, in my template, I do `<div *ngIf="typeIsAuthorized()">`, that div is not rendered. If I instead return this.currentUser().type === systemRoles[systemRoles.Executive], the div is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As can be read [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

> Reverse mappings In addition to creating an object with property names
>   for members, numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from
>   enum values to enum names. For example, in this example:
>
> ```
> enum Enum {
>     A
> }
> let a = Enum.A;
> let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
> ```
>
> TypeScript might compile this down to something like the the following
>
> ```
> JavaScript:
>
> var Enum;
> (function (Enum) {
>     Enum[Enum["A"] = 0] = "A";
> })(Enum || (Enum = {}));
> var a = Enum.A;
> var nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
> ```
>
> In this generated code, **an enum is compiled into an object that
>   stores both forward (name -> value) and reverse (value -> name)
>   mappings**. References to other enum members are always emitted as
>   property accesses and never inlined.
>
> Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping
>   generated at all.

So your enum compiles down to something like this in js

```
{
"0":"Staff",
"1":"DeptMgr",
"2":"Manager",
"3":"GM",
"4":"Executive",
"5":"Owner",
"Staff":0,
"DeptMgr":1,
"Manager":2,
"GM":3,
"Executive":4,
"Owner":5
}
```

So When you do this

```
return systemRoles[this.currentUser().type] === 4
```

due to how enums are compiled 
`systemRoles[this.currentUser().type]` returns a string because either

```
typeof(this.currentUser().type) == typeof(systemRoles)
OR
this.currentUser() is number
```

Where as

```
systemRoles['Executive'] is number
```

**EDIT--**
What you are trying to do actually is a very good use of constant enums. Which is also better performance wise.

As can be read [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

> To avoid paying the cost of extra generated code and additional
>   indirection when accessing enum values, it’s possible to use const
>   enums. Const enums are defined using the const modifier on our enums:
>
> ```
> const enum Enum {
>     A = 1,
>     B = A * 2 
> }
> ```
>
> Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and unlike regular
>   enums they are completely removed during compilation. Const enum
>   members are inlined at use sites. This is possible since const enums
>   cannot have computed members.
>
> ```
> const enum Directions {
>     Up,
>     Down,
>     Left,
>     Right }
> ```
>
> let directions = [Directions.Up, Directions.Down, Directions.Left,
>   Directions.Right] in generated code will become
>
> ```
> var directions = [0 /* Up */, 1 /* Down */, 2 /* Left */, 3 /* Right
> */];
> ```

So Assuming this.currentUser().type is either typeof(systemRoles) or typeof(number).
you will be able to do

```
this.currentUser().type > systemRoles.Executive
```

because ultimately all this will be compiled to a number

Answer (score -1):

Agree to explanation by [Parv Sharma] above. Coming out of the way enums compile you should write:
    return this.currentUser().type === systemRoles[systemRoles.Executive];

systemRoles[systemRoles.Executive] is equal to "Executive" (typeof will give you string), so is this.currentUser().type in your case.

example here
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20systemRoles%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Staff%2C%0D%0A%20%20DeptMgr%2C%0D%0A%20%20Manager%2C%0D%0A%20%20GM%2C%0D%0A%20%20Executive%2C%0D%0A%20%20Owner%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20user1%20%3D%20new%20User()%3B%0D%0Auser1.name%20%3D%20%22e1%22%3B%0D%0Auser1.type%20%3D%20%22Executive%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20user2%20%3D%20new%20User()%3B%0D%0Auser2.name%20%3D%20%22u1%22%3B%0D%0Auser2.type%20%3D%20%22Staff%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20userTypeIsAuthorized(%20user%20)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20user.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20systemRoles%5BsystemRoles.Executive%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(systemRoles%5B%22Executive%22%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(systemRoles%5Buser1.type%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(systemRoles%5BsystemRoles.Executive%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(systemRoles.Executive)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%20user1.type%20)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20systemRoles%5BsystemRoles.Executive%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(typeof%20user1.type)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(userTypeIsAuthorized(user1))%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(userTypeIsAuthorized(%20user2%20))%3B%0D%0A